# How does ICloud drive manage a local copy when the local drive is too small?

Tags: icloud

My MacBook has a 250 GB SSD and I have a 500GB iCloud Drive. The total size of files stored in iCloud is currently about 100 GB, which by default maintains an identical copy of all files in both locations without any user control. The local copy is hidden in ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents.

What files will be removed from the local copy, when the iCloud Drive file size begins to exceed 250 GB?

Comment: Probably no new files will come in, and you'll get "disk space exhausted" messages all around. But what has this to do with StackOverflow?

Comment: The question itself does not directly pertain to a particular language, but the behavior of local copy swapping is relevant to programming.